# Unwrapping car problem, overlapping faces and uv "spaghetti"

Tags: uv

I've made car model. I want to unwrap some details mesh. I've marked seams on all required (I think so) faces/places. Its my first so big model and unwrapping of so many faces. The result is strange:
[image]
It's my .blend file:
[.blend file hyperlink](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=44696)

Comment: I wouldn't perhaps expect a window or windshield of a car to use the same texture as a chrome bumper or a license plate. If this were my model, I would select, for example, just the faces of the bumper, then unwrap those. You can then easily adjust the UVs over your chosen texture. Once finished, deselect those and select others, like only the grill, or only the headlight, then repeat.

Comment: @Metcalf I will use metalness and roughness map,  I want one texture to details, one for interior,  one for chassis and one for wheels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have somehow managed to **Pin** some of the unwrapped vertices. That’s the red dots that appear in the UV editor. They are not really showing in the image you posted but show up in the .blend file you provided.

What you need to do is **Unpin** them and then UV unwrap again.

[image]

Comment: For what is used pin and unpin?  What does this mean?

Comment: Check out Pin and Unpin in the Blender manuel here : https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/uv_image/uv_editing/layout_editing.html